Prime Composite Digit Arrangement
This is an arrangement problem, in which two conditions that are intertwined needs to be dealt with. Here it goes:
In how many five-digit numbers does at least one prime digit appear between two composite digits, and at least one composite digit appear between two prime digits?
I have made it on my own, hence have no way to verify my answer. I am getting the answer as 7680 by forming 4 cases. I am not sure if I have analyzed all possible cases, and if I have done any double or multiple counting by mistake. Can somebody verify my answer and show the steps?

Clarification: leftmost digit can not equal $~0, ~$ prime digits are $~2,3,5,7,~$ and $~1~$ is neither prime nor composite.  Are all of these assumptions accurate?

yes that would be correct assumptions to go ahead with

0 is also not composite. So there are four prime digits (2, 3, 5, 7) and four composite digits (4, 6, 8, 9).

Observe that there are only six possibilities to have prime ($P$) and composite ($C$) digits in a sequence of five digits, where some digits can take on any value ($A$):

$PPCPC$
$PCPCA$
$CCPCP$
$CPCPA$
$1PCPC$
$1CPCP$

In all other cases, at least one of the two conditions is not met. The number of possible sequences corresponding to these cases equals:

$4^5 = 1024$
$4^4 \cdot 10 = 2560$
$4^5 = 1024$
$4^4 \cdot 10 = 2560$
$4^4 = 256$
$4^4 = 256$

This results in a total of $7680$ valid cases. This number can be confirmed through the following Python code:
def is_prime(n):
    return n in [2, 3, 5, 7]


def is_composite(n):
    return n in [4, 6, 8, 9]


n_valid = 0
for i in range(10 ** 4, 10 ** 5):
    a = i // 10000
    b = i // 1000 % 10
    c = i // 100 % 10
    d = i // 10 % 10
    e = i % 10
    composite_between_primes = (is_prime(a) and is_composite(b) and is_prime(c)) or \
                               (is_prime(b) and is_composite(c) and is_prime(d)) or \
                               (is_prime(c) and is_composite(d) and is_prime(e))
    prime_between_composites = (is_composite(a) and is_prime(b) and is_composite(c)) or \
                               (is_composite(b) and is_prime(c) and is_composite(d)) or \
                               (is_composite(c) and is_prime(d) and is_composite(e))
    if composite_between_primes and prime_between_composites:
        n_valid += 1
print(n_valid)

